# Can you omit the noun after the adjective 'own' that follows the genitive of an NP?

Tags: possessives, ellipsis, genitive-construction

> a. The opposition party approves of the policy, but the president's own party doesn't.

Can you omit the noun 'party' like this?

> b. The opposition party approves of the policy, but the president's own doesn't.

Comment: yes, I guess this, "the opposition party approves of the policy, but the president's doesn't" is also possible.